# Play sound on specific time of a day in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, push-notification

I want to play a sound on some specific time of a day like 5.00 P.M Daily. Is there any way we can do such thing or we can modify alarm class to make this this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know - you cannot do this. Check ScheduledActionService and what it offers. Check also BackgroundTask and BackgroundAgents out. You can only set reminder or toast notification which when will be clicked can navigate you to your app and then you can play a sound. 
In scheduled BackgroundAgents not all APIs are available.

http://www.abhishekshukla.com/silverlight/windows-phone-7-mango-background/ all you need should be here